# C# gives an error if string is converted to int

Tags: c#, string, int

Simple calculator in C#
I'm not able to understand why I get an exception on taking any of the inputs in class Calculator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char choice = '7';
        while (choice != '3')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------Calculator---------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\n1.Add\n2.Subtract\n3.Multiply\n4.Divide\n5.Modulo-Operation (remainder)\n6.Exit\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice:");
            choice = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            switch (choice)
            {
                case '1':
                    Calculator.Add();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Calculator.Subtract();
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Calculator.Multiply();
                    break;
                case '4':
                    Calculator.Divide();
                    break;
                case '5':
                    Calculator.Modulo();
                    break;
                case '6':
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice.\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Calculator
{

    public static void Add()
    {
        int a, b;
        string sa, sb;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:\n");
        sa = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        a = Convert.ToInt32(sa);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
        sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        Console.Write("{0}\n", a + b);
    }
    public static void Subtract()
    {
        int a, b;
        string sa, sb;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:\n");
        sa = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        a = Convert.ToInt32(sa);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
        sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        Console.Write("{0}\n", a - b);
    }
    public static void Multiply()
    {
        int a, b;
        string sa, sb;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:\n");
        sa = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        a = Convert.ToInt32(sa);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
        sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        Console.Write("{0}\n", a * b);
    }
    public static void Divide()
    {
        int a, b;
        string sa,sb;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:\n");
        sa = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        a = Convert.ToInt32(sa);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
        sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        while (b == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In division operation, divisor cannot be zero.\n Retry!!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
            sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        }
        Console.Write("{0}\n", a / b);
    }
    public static void Modulo()
    {
        int a, b;
        string sa, sb;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:\n");
        sa = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        a = Convert.ToInt32(sa);
        while (a < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In modulo operation, first number cannot be negative.\n Retry!!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
            sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:\n");
        sb = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        b = Convert.ToInt32(sb);
        Console.Write("{0}\n", a % b);
    }
}
}
```

I always get an error like "FormatException:" error converting string to  DateTime

Comment: Please boil this down to a [mcve].  Also, what specific string are you trying to convert to a date time?

Comment: You can get answers faster if you provide a line number where exception is thrown

Comment: Paste the exact exception. In this code you are not using `DateTime` so you can`t get _error converting string to DateTime_

Comment: The exception really recommends: _"when converting a string to DateTime, parse ..."_ as troubleshooting tip. The `DateTime` part is confusing if you used `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: Oh, you are right @TimSchmelter . I never notice that part

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line

```
choice = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

This reads only one char from the input, but if you press '1', followed by the enter key, your code enters the Add method and then retrieve immediately the newline you have pressed after the 1.
This is not a valid integer and Convert.ToInt32 fails.

Change to

```
string choice = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
```

and modify your switch to handle a string instead of a char

Said that, you need to change your code for another problem. Convert.ToInt32 fails with an exception if you try to convert an input that is not a valid integer. You should look at how to use Int32.TryParse and take appropriate action if the input is not valid

For example

```
string sa, sb;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:\n");
sa = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
if(!Int32.TryParse(sa, out a))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type a number");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I was still wondering why `Console.ReadLine()` didn't wait for the input. :)

Comment: As an alternative, as OP just one 1 character to select the options, you could do just `choice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);` This has the advantage of not needing user to press enter